# Mock fs function with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, fs, winston

First of all, I'm new to `es6` and `jest`.

I have a `Logger` class for instantiate `winston` and I would like to test it.

Here my code :

```
const winston = require('winston');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('../config.json');

class Logger {
  constructor() {
    Logger.createLogDir(Logger.logDir);
    this.logger = winston.createLogger({
      level: 'info',
      format: winston.format.json(),
      transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
          format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
            winston.format.simple(),
          ),
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({
          filename: path.join(Logger.logDir, '/error.log'),
          level: 'error',
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({
          filename: path.join(Logger.logDir, '/info.log'),
          level: 'info',
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({
          filename: path.join(Logger.logDir, '/combined.log'),
        }),
      ],
    });
  }

  static get logDir() {
    return (config.logDir == null) ? 'log' : config.logDir;
  }

  static createLogDir(logDir) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
      // Create the directory if it does not exist
      fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
    }
  }
}

exports.logger = new Logger().logger;
export default new Logger();
```

I would like to test my function `createLogDir()`.
I my head, I think it's a good idea to test the state of fs.existsSync.
If `fs.existsSync` return `false`, `fs.mkdirSync` must  be called.
So I try to write some `jest` test :

```
describe('logDir configuration', () => {
  test('default path must be used', () => {
    const logger = require('./logger');
    jest.mock('fs');
    fs.existsSync = jest.fn();
    fs.existsSync.mockReturnValue(false);
    const mkdirSync = jest.spyOn(logger, 'fs.mkdirSync');
    expect(mkdirSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

However, I've got an error :

```
  ● logDir configuration › default path must be used

    Cannot spy the fs.mkdirSync property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

      18 |     fs.existsSync = jest.fn();
      19 |     fs.existsSync.mockReturnValue(true);
    > 20 |     const mkdirSync = jest.spyOn(logger, 'fs.mkdirSync');
      21 |     expect(mkdirSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
      22 |   });
      23 | });

      at ModuleMockerClass.spyOn (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:590:15)
      at Object.test (src/logger.test.js:20:28)
```

Can you help me to debug and test my function please ?

Regards.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The error there is because it is looking for a method called `fs.mkdirSync` on your `logger` object, which doesn't exist. If you had access to the `fs` module in your test then you would spy on the `mkdirSync` method like this:

```
jest.spyOn(fs, 'mkdirSync');
```

However, I think you need to take a different approach.

Your `createLogDir` function is a static method - meaning that it can only be called on the class, and not on an instance of that class (`new Logger()` is an instance of the class `Logger`). Therefore, in order to test that function you need to export the class and not an instance of it, i.e.:

```
module.exports = Logger;
```

Then you could have the following tests:

```
const Logger = require('./logger');
const fs = require('fs');

jest.mock('fs') // this auto mocks all methods on fs - so you can treat fs.existsSync and fs.mkdirSync like you would jest.fn()

it('should create a new log directory if one doesn\'t already exist', () => {
    // set up existsSync to meet the `if` condition
    fs.existsSync.mockReturnValue(false);

    // call the function that you want to test
    Logger.createLogDir('test-path');

    // make your assertion
    expect(fs.mkdirSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('should NOT create a new log directory if one already exists', () => {
    // set up existsSync to FAIL the `if` condition
    fs.existsSync.mockReturnValue(true);

    Logger.createLogDir('test-path');

    expect(fs.mkdirSync).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Note: it looks like you're mixing CommonJS and es6 module syntax (`export default` is es6) - I would try to stick to one or the other

Comment: I think this pattern doesn't allow for the real FS methods to be restored. This permanently alters the test environment in ways that could affect other tests. You'll need to use `jest.spyOn(fs, 'mkdirSync')` so you can later do `fs.mkdirSync.mockRestore()`.

Comment: @Billy winston will automatically create new folder do we need to write extra code for that one

Comment: @Billy i was also implementing the above one can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250372/logger-implementation-using-winston-morgan-and-winston-daily-rotate-file , will be a help for me

Comment: @Tom you're right, have changed to auto mocking so it wouldn't affect other tests

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this with

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
```

then

```
jest.doMock('fs', () => fs)
```

this should fix your problem.