# Mock 'fs' module in jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, fs

I'm trying to mock the `fs` module like so:

`jest.mock('fs');`

And as seen in this post - [Mock fs function with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066138/mock-fs-function-with-jest)

I should be able to treat the functions inside the module as `jest.fn()` and use - `fs.existsSync.mockReturnValue(false);` for instance.

That however does not seem to work and typescript gives me a bunch of errors.
All I want to do is assert a couple of functions like `mkdirSync` to have been called times or with some parameters and I seem to be running into this error -

`'The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined'`

I tried to add `fs.ts` to the `__mocks__` folder and mock it there - but that was no luck.

The file I am trying to test is a class and it imports fs. I am creating a new class instance in the `beforeEach` jest method.

So generally speaking, I don't really care to create a file or see if it exists, I wish to have a mocked return value or an implementation and just check with what parameters the `fs` module functions have been called.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that running jest and mocking the file system in any way results in a conflict as jest is also using the fs module to handle the run.

The only solution i have found to overcome this issue:

```
export class SomeClass {
    fs: typeof fs;
    constructor() { this.fs = fs }
    ///code
}
```

Mock the fs methods like so in a test:

```
someClass.fs = {
    mkdirSync: jest.fn()
} as any;
```

Assertion:

```
expect(someClass.fs.mkdirSync).toBeCalledWith('parameters');
```