# Cannot mock fs with jest using typescript - Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, automocking

**Problem:**

Would someone help me figure out how to mock fs with jest using typescript? I've tried a few things, and here is the main one:

I'm attempting to use jest to mock 'fs', but I can't seem to get jest to automock the 'fs' library in Typescript.

Here is my code:

```
import fs from 'fs';

jest.mock('fs');

describe('helloWorld.ts', () => {
  it('foobar', () => {

    fs.readdirSync.mockReturnValue(['foo.js', 'bar.js']);
  })
});
```

Typescript tells me "Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type..."

[image: cannot mock fs with jest]

**Environment:**

Node v14.15.1

Typescript: "^4.0.3"

VS Code Typescript: 4.1.2

**On a related note, I tried this with spyOn and it failed:**

I tried to use this but couldn't get `spyOn` to work either (reference: [jest typescript property mock does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457575/jest-typescript-property-mock-does-not-exist-on-type) )

```
import fs from 'fs';

describe('helloWorld.ts', () => {
  it('foobar', () => {
    jest.spyOn(fs, 'readdirSync').mockImplementation(() => {
      return ['foo.js', 'bar.js'];
    });
    console.log(fs.readdirSync('.'));
  });
});
```

This code fails with this typescript error TS2345:

```
Argument of type '() => string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(path: PathLike, options: BaseEncodingOptions & { withFileTypes: true; }) => Dirent[]'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Dirent[]'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Dirent'.
```

**Related references:**

- This appears to be related, but I feel there's a better solution: [Mock 'fs' module in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774426/mock-fs-module-in-jest)
- Jest has an issue here that suggests that mocking 'fs' should work when explicitly mocked with `jest.mock('fs')` https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler does not know anything about `fs` being a mock.

You can tell it about this by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```js
(<jest.Mock>fs.readdirSync).mockReturnValue(...);
```

It becomes tedious work to do this everytime you use mocked functions imported from the `fs` module. To make the things simpler you can declare a variable whose type is a module mock, initialize it with `fs` and use it instead of `fs` in the tests:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

jest.mock('fs');

const mockFS: jest.Mocked<typeof fs> = <jest.Mocked<typeof fs>>fs;

describe('helloWorld.ts', () => {
  it('foobar', () => {

    mockFS.readdirSync.mockReturnValue(['foo.js', 'bar.js']);
  });
});
```

Comment: That was it and that solved it, thank you for the quick response! I'll accept this when SO lets me